# Creating table with date inputs in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

My goal is to create a dashboard that has in one of the tabs a table based on date inputs from the user. I want this to be specifically in the tab called Overview in the dashboard.

I have 3 r scripts, one called data cleaning thats basically a table loaded into a data frame called **trans**. The other 2 are called ui and server. They are the following:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)#For fread.
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)#For the interactive table.



# Header -----------------------------------------------------------------------|
header<-dashboardHeader( title = "Marketing Dashboard"
  
)


# Sidebar ----------------------------------------------------------------------|

sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Overview", tabname ="overview", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Weather", tabname ="weather", icon = icon("bolt"))
  )
)

# Body -------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  
body<-dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = 'Overview',
      fluidRow(     
        dateRangeInput("date",
          label = 'Date range input',
          start = Sys.Date() - 7, end = Sys.Date()
        ),
        dataTableOutput("overviewtable")
      )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = 'weather',
      fluidRow(
        
      )
    )
  )
)



# UI ---------------------------------------------------------------------------|

ui = dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**server.R**

```
server <- function(input,output){
  
  #Reactive for dates in overview
  overviewdata<- reactive({
   trans %>% filter(ymd_hms(start_time) >= input$date[1] & ymd_hms(end_time)<= inpute$date[2])
  })
  #Table for overview
  output$overviewtable<- renderDataTable(
    datatable({
      overviewdata
    })
  )
  
  
}
```

My problem is when I run the app I see only a blank dashboard with two tabs. One for Overview and one for Weather. I don't see any table or any place where it gives me the option to input the dates. This is my first time working with shiny and I am trying to learn on the go. It is also my first time working with multiple r scripts.
I have looked at other examples online from r gallery and from stack overflow but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to be consistent on what you call `tabName` (note the camelCase!). `tabName = 'overview'` and it works. We cannot comment on your data trans, as we don't have it.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out but when I change it to lowercase, I still have basically a blank app. The input dates and the table do not show up. Im not allowed to share the trans table but all it is, is simply a data frame.

Comment: @Martin I did not understand what you meant at first but now I see thank you. That indeed fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the dateRangeInput inside the menuItem if you want to see it inside the tab. Here's what it would look like under the "Overview" tab.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)#For fread.
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)#For the interactive table.



# Header -----------------------------------------------------------------------|
header<-dashboardHeader( title = "Marketing Dashboard"
                         
)


# Sidebar ----------------------------------------------------------------------|

sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Overview", tabname ="overview", icon = icon("dashboard"),
             dateRangeInput("date",
                            label = 'Date range input',
                            start = Sys.Date() - 7, end = Sys.Date()
             )),
    menuItem("Weather", tabname ="weather", icon = icon("bolt"))
  )
)

# Body -------------------------------------------------------------------------|

body<-dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = 'Overview',
            fluidRow(     
              dataTableOutput("overviewtable")
            )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = 'weather',
            fluidRow(
              
            )
    )
  )
)



# UI ---------------------------------------------------------------------------|

ui = dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I did as you said and now I do see the input range in the sidebar menu but I still have the problem that I do not see the table in the overview tab.